# Why getting an item from an object returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get the item "Errors" from the object below:

```
{Id: 15, Date: "22-02-2019", Time: "22:45", Sport: "Football", Country: "United Kingdom", …}
    Bet: "Win"
    Bookie: "Bet365"
    Competition: "Premier League"
    Country: "United Kingdom"
    Currency: "Euro"
    Date: "22-02-2019"
    Home: "Cardiff"
    Id: 15
    Odds: "1.45"
    Sport: "Football"
    Stake: "5.110"
    Status: "Won"
    Time: "22:45"
    Visitor: ""
    Εrrors: Array(2)
        0: (2) ["date", Array(1)]
        1: (2) ["visitor", Array(1)]
        length: 2
        __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__: Object
```

The object is included in a array of objects as the response of an ajax call made to an api endpoint.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/import",
        headers: {"X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get('csrftoken')},
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (res) {
        ....}
    })
```

Calling `rowData["Date"]` or `rowData["Time"]` returns the appropriate values.

If I do `rowData["Errors"]` I get `undefined`. I can't figure out if it can't find the Errors attribute or it's something else.

I need to get the Errors so I can iterate through them and display them on the page.

I have used JS mainly for DOM manipulation and this has really stumped me.

**The lesson here is be careful of your spelling especially with letters that might be shared in english and your language.**

Comment: `rowData{"Errors"]` should throw a `SyntaxError`, not return `undefined`. Please post a [MCVE], as *text*, not as an image (don't post images of code)

Comment: Assuming that was a typo you'll need to provide some context for the code, e.g., is this coming as the result of an async call?

Comment: I have added some more code to explain further what I am doing.

Comment: The first letter of `Εrror` is a greek `Ε`, so fix your backend. (*voting to close as a typo*)

Comment: That’s also why `Εrrors` isn’t highlighted here.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli It was just a spelling mistake here and on my actual code. Specificaly not on my js code but on the django viewset method.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli i also voted to be closed. Thanks for the simple but very useful observation. Although, a KeyError like in Python would be so useful.

Comment: You are welcome, I am also greek and assumed by your name the same and so thought it might be such an issue..

Answer (score 2):

You need to use all square brackets `[]` for this:

```
rowData["Errors"];
```

But since this is a property name without spaces or special characters, you can use simple dot notation which will work perfectly:

```
rowData.Errors;
```

Comment: I have tried what you mention with the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you post the `rowData` object as code, not an image? It's possible you have nested objects, but we can't tell due to the presentation.